# Como puedo hacer $push solo de 5 elementos en un schema en MongoDB

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, mongoose, mongod

Estoy intentando hacer una query donde solo me regrese digamos 3 elementos por cada hashtag. Hasta ahora he logrado que me regrese algo como esto

```
{
    "_id": "Grill",
    "count": 3,
    "opcion": [
      {
        "_id": "1",
        "description": "Post",
        "hashtags": "Grill",
        "files": [
          "file1"
        ],
        "cover": "picture.png"
      },
      {
        "_id": "2",
        "description": "Probando publicación",
        "hashtags": "Grill",
        "files": [
          "file1"
        ],
        "cover": "picture.png"
      },
      {
        "_id": "3",
        "description": "Probando ",
        "files": [
          "file1"
        ],
        "cover": "picture.png"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

El problema es que cuando sean datos reales van a ser cientos de posts con este hashtag, como podria hacer que de cada hashtag solo me regrese una pequeña cantidad? Ya he probado con filter y con sample pero esos 2 solo me regresan los hashtag

**Esta es mi query hasta ahora**

```
Posts.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$hashtags" },
    {
      "$group":
      {
        "_id": "$hashtags",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        // "max": { "$max": 3 },
        "opcion": {
          "$push": {
            _id: '$_id',
            description: '$description',
            hashtags: '$hashtags',
            files: '$files',
            cover: '$cover',
          }
       },
      }
    }
  ]).sort({ "count": -1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea obtener una cantidad de elementos determinados en un `Array` durante una etapa de agrupamiento [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)  sobre una colección en MongoDB.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Si mal no he entendido tu pregunta, deseas devolver una cantidad, (digamos **X**), de elementos en el campo `opcion`, pero manteniendo el valor del conteo total de elementos (campo `count`).

Una solución es usar el operador de [proyección](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) llamado [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/), el cual devuelve precisamente una cantidad determinada de elementos de un campo de tipo lista en un documento (o documentos) de una colección.

Por ejemplo, tu código podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```js
Posts.aggregate([
    // Etapa unwind
    { $unwind: '$hashtags' },
    // Etapa group
    {
      $group:
      {
        _id: $hashtags',
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        opcion: {
          $push: {
            _id: '$_id',
            description: '$description',
            hashtags: '$hashtags',
            files: '$files',
            cover: '$cover',
          }
       },
      }
    },
    // Etapa project
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,    // <- indico que deseo devolver el campo _id
        count: 1,  // <- indico que deseo devolver el campo count
        opcion_muestra: {  // <- digo que el campo opcion es una muestra
          $slice: [ '$opcion', 5 ] // <- aplico $slice sobre el campo '$opcion' y devuelvo 5 elementos (los primeros 5)
        }
      }
    }
  ]).sort({ count: -1 })
```

De esta forma estarás devolviendo al menos los primeros 5 elementos pertenecientes al campo `opcion`. Si el campo `opcion` tiene menos de 5 elementos, devuelve todos los que contenga. También puedes notar que he llamado al campo `opcion_muestra` ya que no contiene todos los elementos del campo `opcion`, solamente 5.

Puedes devolver elementos específicos de acuerdo al índice de su posición en el `Array`, sin embargo, lo usual para el caso de uso que planteas es devolver los primeros *n* elementos. También podrías aplicar una etapa de ordenamiento ([`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)) si deseas ordenar los documentos antes de agruparlos, de esta forma puedes obtener los últimos 5 elementos (imagina que ordenas por fecha descendente o alfabéticamente según un campo dado) o los primeros 5 elementos, pero esto ya depende de lo que necesites.

En [este MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CpzyNGduwkf) puedes ver un ejemplo de la salida, se generan 50 documentos de forma aleatoria, y en el campo `opcion_muestra` sólo se hace `push` de 2 elementos, puedes ver que el campo `count` de cada documento muestra la cantidad de documentos totales de cada `hashtag`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.